# MySql join two lines in the same lines

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select, phpmyadmin

I try to join two tables in the same line.
I try this

```
SELECT p.*
     , t.joursPrevus joursInge 
  FROM projet p
  JOIN temps t
    ON t.projet_id = p.idProjet 
 WHERE t.role_id = 1
 UNION
SELECT p.*
     , t.joursPrevus joursTech 
  FROM projet p 
  JOIN temps t
    ON t.projet_id = p.idProjet 
 WHERE t.role_id = 2
```

but I obtain this 
[my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hdezs.png)
but I want to union this table :
[table 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0SeS.png)
and [table 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7thEU.png)
with the same idProjet on the same line and role_id: 1 is joursInge and role_id: 2 is joursTech

i try to have a row like:

**idProjet** - **nom** - **client** - **achatsPrevus** - **achatsRestants** - **dateDebut** - **dateFin** - **fini** - **joursPrevus(role_id:1)** - **joursPrevus(role_id:2)**

If something has had the solution to do what I want, because I'm stuck !

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: The code you write should always be in english! All the names you choose (table names, table columns, aliases in sql queries) should be in english. Only the data can be localized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the simplest approach is to `join` twice:

```
SELECT p.*, t1.joursPrevus AS joursInge, t2.joursPrevus AS joursTech
FROM projet p
INNER JOIN temps t1 ON t1.projet_id = p.idProjet  AND t1.role_id = 1
INNER JOIN temps t2 ON t2.projet_id = p.idProjet  AND t2.role_id = 2
```

This assumes no missing roles in table `temps` for each and every project - otherwise, you can use `left join` instead.